# iOS7 Browser crash (Safari / Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, safari, crash, ios7

Some internetprojects I developed long time agoo, like http://psvfans.edprojecten.nl/, always worked fine on my iPad and iPhone.

These projects won't load in iOS7 and the browser will crash. I've tested my example project (http://psvfans.edprojecten.nl/) on a iPad2 (iOS7) in Safari and Chrome. It crashed: won't load, black window, back to home screen. I also tested it on a iPhone 4S (iOS7) in Safari and Chrome: same story.

I've tested my project the same time on a iPhone 3GS (it can't update to iOS7, so it still uses iOS6) and it works fine! Found also someone who didn't update his iPad2 and still uses iOS6: the project works fine.

In case my project will crash in Safari AND in Chrome, this is not a Safari problem. I think the problem is iOS7.

Does anyone know what's the change in iOS7, why my project will crashs?

Answer (score 0):

iOs7 imposes significant memory limitations. Every iOs7 browser crashing issue I've encountered or heard of has revolved around a memory issue.